# For loop to convert multiple columns to factors in R

Tags: r

I have few columns which I need to convert to factors

```
for cols in ['col1','col2']:
  df$cols<-as.factor(as.character(df$cols))
```

Error

```
for cols in ['col1','col2']:
Error: unexpected symbol in "for cols"
>   df$cols<-as.factor(as.character(df$cols))
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, cols, value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 942
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax showed also use the `python` `for` loop and python `list`.  Instead it would be a `vector` of strings in `R

```
for (col in c('col1','col2')) {
       df[[col]] <- factor(df[[col]])
  }
```

NOTE: here we use `[[` instead of `$` and the braces `{}`.  The `factor` can be directly applied instead of `as.character` wrapping

---

Or with `lapply` where it can be done easily (without using any packages)

```
df[c('col1', 'col2')] <- lapply(df[c('col1', 'col2')], factor)
```

---

Or in `dplyr`, where it can be done more easily

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
          mutate_at(vars(col1, col2), factor)
```

Answer (score 1):

In complement to @akrun solution, with `data.table`, this can be done easily:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[,c("col1","col2") := lapply(.SD, function(c) as.factor(as.character(c))), .SDcols = c("col1","col2")]
```

Note that `df` is updated by reference (`:=`) so no need for reassignment